# Tracking client's disk usage and bandwidth

Tags: ubuntu, shared-hosting, monitoring, resource-management

I run a shared server (Ubuntu Linux) with up to 20 client websites on it.

Does anyone know of an application that will allow me to track the disk usage of each client (apache VHOST) and bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

There's a module (Logio) that you can install for Apache that will do this for you. You can find it [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_logio.html)